# make error in OpenCV installation on ubuntu (ffmpeg CODEC_ID_XXXX was not declared in scope)

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.10

I am trying to install OpenCV following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubOa_tJDM_U) tutorial. I am through cmake.(The configuration is given at the end.) However make shows error :`make[2]: ***[modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp.o] Error 1`
One [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/12597/build-problems-for-opencv-241-with-ubuntu-1204-lts/) pointed out reason as different version of opencv and ffmpeg, but I found a piece of code in cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp that appears to be handling it.

```
#if LIBAVCODEC_BUILD >= CALC_FFMPEG_VERSION(54,25,0)
#  define CV_CODEC_ID AVCodecID
#  define CV_CODEC(name) AV_##name
#else
#  define CV_CODEC_ID CodecID
#  define CV_CODEC(name) name
#endif
```

Not sure if it is ok for this to be commented.

Also, I could try installing ffmpeg seperately, but I am not sure how dependencies are handled in this installation around libav.

Would be thankful for any help in solving this problem, as well as tips/links for OpenCV installation in general.

make configuration:

```
-- General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.11 ====================================
Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 3.16.0-32-generic i686
--     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.9.1)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml video legacy objdetect photo gpu ocl nonfree contrib java python stitching superres ts videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera dynamicuda viz
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT 5.x:                      YES (ver 5.3.0)
--     QT OpenGL support:           YES (Qt5::OpenGL 5.3.0)
--     OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so)
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.51)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.3)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 1.6.1)
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.1)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 56.1.0)
--       format:                    YES (ver 56.1.0)
--       util:                      YES (ver 54.3.0)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 3.0.0)
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.2.1) / libv4l2 (ver 1.2.1)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.1)
--     Use TBB:                     YES (ver 4.2 interface 7000)
--     Use OpenMP:                  NO
--     Use GCD                      NO
--     Use Concurrency              NO
--     Use C=:                      NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/keeda/Downloads/data_analysis/opencv-2.4.11/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMD FFT:                 NO
--     Use AMD BLAS:                NO
-- 
--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.8)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.8)
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.9.1)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.9.4)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java tests:                  YES
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Build Documentation:         YES
--     Sphinx:                      /usr/bin/sphinx-build (ver 1.2.2)
--     PdfLaTeX compiler:           /usr/bin/pdflatex
--     Doxygen:                     NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/keeda/Downloads/data_analysis/opencv-2.4.11/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in the link you've posted? It shows you how to get `ffmpeg`

Comment: sad news. I ignored ffmpeg and installed.( i had to work more with pictures than video stream)